# std::async with class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I'm kind of new to `std::async` and I have problems understanding how it works. I saw example of how to pass member funcion to `std::async` somewhere on the web but it seems not to compile. Whats the problem here? How can it be done without lambda?

```
class Test {
  std::future<void> f;
  void test() {}
  void runTest() {
    // ERROR no instance overloaded matches argument list
    f = std::async(std::launch::async, &Test::test, this); 

    // OK...
    f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this] {test();}); 
  }
  void testRes() {
    f.get();
  }
};
```

Comment: is `void Test::test()` an overloaded member function?

Comment: No, it is not. Tried to keep minimal reproducible example as close as it is in original source :)

Comment: What compiler and version? There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown. Please include headers, `main()` etc so it's a [mcve].

Comment: The information provided here is not sufficient to help you, at best we can only make educated guesses. please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use std::bind to create a callable function object:

```
f = std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&Test::test, this));
```

In your example &Test::test is not a function that takes one parameter of type `Test`, as it would be expected by `std::async`. Instead it is member function, which must be called differently.